# AWS QLDB multi region support

Tags: amazon-web-services, distributed-transactions, amazon-qldb

I am working on QLDB from last 3 months on a single region using it as a leisure database.  Now, business wants to move applications in multi-region support. I found many of the AWS services support multi-region like DynamoDB, Secrets Manager.

But there is limitations on QLDB for multi-region use. I saw from some AWS articles that QLDB does not have support for multi-region as it's not a distributed technology.

Now, to cater business requirement with minimal changes in code, I have to approaches/workaround for QLDB to support multi-region.

1. Do I need to create region-based ledger, with same functionality? I understand there are major challenges with maintaining the geo-based traffic.
2. I will keep QLDB ledger in single region and gives cross-region access permissions to Lambda functions to access it. It's a simplest one but eat latency.

Which approach helps in long term and in scalability? Or please suggest if anyone has different approach to achieve this.

Comment: Posted a solution, did it clarify?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to create region based leisure, with same functionality? I understand there are major challenges with maintaining the geo based traffic.

Yes, at this moment. Like you said, there is no multi-region support or global in AWS jargon, you need to create region-based leisure **on your own.**

> to cater business requirement with minimal changes in code

You can achieve cross region replication by following [the docs](https://aws.amazon.com/qldb/faqs/#Availability.2C_Durability.2C_and_Replication).

> Amazon QLDB does not support cross-region replication as of now. QLDB's export to S3 feature enables customers to export the contents of the QLDB journal to a S3 bucket. The S3 buckets can be configured for cross-region replication.

Side note :

> I will keep QLDB leisure in single region and gives cross region access permissions to Lambda functions to access it. It's a simplest one but eat latency.

If your business wants multi-region support this option would not satisfy their conditions.